# How to remove array based on specific value?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays.

```
var allAuth = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let thomasauth = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

let res = allAuth.filter(f => !thomasauth.includes(f));
```

I am returning the missing matching value from `allAuth` array which is 1.

I want to remove 1 from `allAuth` array.

I currently have

```
let filteredArr = allAuth.filter(e => e !== res)
```

but this just gives me back the allAuth array without anything being removed.
my desired output should be

```
let filteredArr = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: *I want to remove 1 from allAuth array.* contracts with *I am returning the missing matching value from allAuth array which is 1.* If you understand the difference, you will find your answer

Answer (score 1):

Change `!thomasauth.includes(f)` to `thomasauth.includes(f)` so to filter only the included items (1 will be excepted in that case.)

```js
var allAuth = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let thomasauth = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

let res = allAuth.filter(f => thomasauth.includes(f));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out your code? You will see that `res` is actually an array containing the values you want to remove (`[1]`) and not a single scalar value.

So I think you intended to do this:

```
let filteredArr = allAuth.filter(e => !res.includes(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var allAuth = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let thomasauth = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

let result = allAuth.filter(val => thomasauth.indexOf(val) !== -1);
console.log(result);
```